# Sendgrid + Nuxt 3 (Send email)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sendgrid

I have a problem sending emails using the Sengrid API. I tested the connection using Postman and everything works fine - the problem is with my code :(

Please edit my code. The folder contains an .env file with a token active for 2 days.

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/jeden-forked-vlhfrq?file=%2Fmail%2Fapp.vue%3A42%2C57

Comment: I'm sorry you ran into a issue. Please rephrase the question with a minimal example to get help. This is not a forum to ask people to fix your code. Also, please never expose an API key to the public - you don't want other people to exploit this :)

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @kissu "Access to fetch at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS." I'm a newbie, that's why I asked you to edit my code

Comment: This is not how you will learn anything tho. Did you googled that error?